# Message Formatting with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to similar function in Excel to jave Message format. Prefer not to use =concat

Example:

```
CELL B1:
Some text with value from cell {A1} added.
```

Is this possible with Excel?

Comment: `="Some text with value from cell {"&A1&"} added."`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ScottCraner That was it. Feel free to post as answer.

Comment: I do not think it is possible with Excel ~

Answer (score 0):

No, what you want is not directly possible with Excel. It simply does not do two things:  1) Support Java message format/ting as a formal, programmed in thing, and 2) Allow "inline" formatting in most any way you'd define such.

However, you can easily create the above message using Excel tools, and do not need to include `CONCAT` in what you do.

For instance, `Scott Craner` notes in the comments, Excel allows string joining via the `&` operator. So you could have the following:

="Some text with value from cell "  &  A1  &  " added."

and if the content in cell A1 were `{A1}` it would read as in your question.

In this case, the first `&` replaces the Java message `{` and the second replaces the `}`. So same thing, but different characters. As in all moving from one program to another.

The main conceptual problem is that Excel flat does not allow FORMAL inline formatting. You could slip in a date or time and use the `TEXT` function to format it for character layout and adding prefixes or suffixes, that kind of thing, basically just adjusting the character string it outputs, but you cannot format it to change font, color, etc.

If that fits your needs, use the `&` to joing pieces of the string you are building and `TEXT` if there are numerical values to format in some way. Outside of that, no, Excel has no built-in way for you to, say, copy over a string you like from the Java message world and bang, you're done. You have to learn a couple small things and do it Excel's way.

The funny thing is, from a programmer background's point of view, the `CONCATENATE` or `CONCAT` functions should make everything look "natural"... but no, you need not use either.